# GetReservationRS has duplicate PRICEQUOTE Summary PQR Information

Tags: sabre

Situation: 2 pax have tickets re-issued due to return date change. Means there is 495.00 Additional Collection. In the PriceQuote/Summary area of the response for one pax the PQR data is repeated. For the other pax it is only listed once as you would expect. In the AccountingLines section of the response it is correctly listed once for each pax. The problem starts on line 13 below with two PQR records. Is this a bug?

```
  <Summary>
    <NameAssociation firstName="JOHN MR" lastName="SMITH" nameId="1" nameNumber="1.1">
      <PriceQuote number="1" pricingType="S" status="A" type="PQ">
        <Indicators itineraryChange="true" />
        <Passenger passengerTypeCount="2" requestedType="ADT" type="ADT" />
        <ItineraryType>I</ItineraryType>
        <ValidatingCarrier>VA</ValidatingCarrier>
        <Amounts>
          <Total currencyCode="AUD" decimalPlace="2">1697.66</Total>
        </Amounts>
        <LocalCreateDateTime>2019-10-31T14:56:00</LocalCreateDateTime>
      </PriceQuote>
      <PriceQuote number="2" pricingType="S" reissueType="EXCH AC" status="A" type="PQR">
        <Indicators ticketed="true" />
        <Passenger passengerTypeCount="1" type="ADT" />
        <Amounts>
          <ReissueDifference currencyCode="AUD" decimalPlace="2">495.00</ReissueDifference>
        </Amounts>
      </PriceQuote>
      <PriceQuote number="3" pricingType="S" reissueType="EXCH AC" status="A" type="PQR">
        <Indicators ticketed="true" />
        <Passenger passengerTypeCount="1" type="ADT" />
        <Amounts>
          <ReissueDifference currencyCode="AUD" decimalPlace="2">495.00</ReissueDifference>
        </Amounts>
      </PriceQuote>
    </NameAssociation>
    <NameAssociation firstName="PAUL MR" lastName="SMITH" nameId="2" nameNumber="2.1">
      <PriceQuote number="1" pricingType="S" status="A" type="PQ">
        <Indicators itineraryChange="true" />
        <Passenger passengerTypeCount="2" requestedType="ADT" type="ADT" />
        <ItineraryType>I</ItineraryType>
        <ValidatingCarrier>VA</ValidatingCarrier>
        <Amounts>
          <Total currencyCode="AUD" decimalPlace="2">1697.66</Total>
        </Amounts>
        <LocalCreateDateTime>2019-10-31T14:56:00</LocalCreateDateTime>
      </PriceQuote>
      <PriceQuote number="4" pricingType="S" reissueType="EXCH AC" status="A" type="PQR">
        <Indicators ticketed="true" />
        <Passenger passengerTypeCount="1" type="ADT" />
        <Amounts>
          <ReissueDifference currencyCode="AUD" decimalPlace="2">495.00</ReissueDifference>
        </Amounts>
      </PriceQuote>
    </NameAssociation>
  </Summary>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a PNR booking error caused by delayed CC validation